# Building a unity-gain op amp with speaker?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, speakers, sine

I am trying to build a voltage follower op-amp circuit to hear a sine wave but I can't get it to work. I was using the LM386 but then found out that it has a gain of 20 by default so I can't use it. I am inputting a sine wave however when it gets to a capacitor it becomes heavily attenuated. What op amp can I use for this? How do I design this circuit? I've tried this circuit it didn't lead anywhere[image]

Comment: It would have been better to use the LM386. So what if it has a gain of 20. Attenuate by 20 first and let the LM386 amplify it back. Usually amplitude of any signal is irrelevat if you just want to drive a speaker, you anyway want to control the volume. So what is the original problem, if two of your solutions have not solved it already?

Comment: That is a good idea, I think I'll build this voltage divider

Comment: What do you mean by "when it gets to a capacitor"? Do you mean when it gets to C1, as shown in the schematic (and if so, what type of capacitor is it)? Or do you mean a (not yet shown) capacitor elsewhere in the signal chain, such as at the input of OA2?

Comment: Hi when I built the original circuit, it was a voltage follower and I had a capacitor as the load. I could see the attenuation happening. My original circuit schematic had an LM386 and it worked perfectly, that's not uploaded here. What's uploaded here was my attempt at driving a speaker using a regular op amp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LM386 is designed to drive an 8-ohm loudspeaker - it is a good solution.

But let's modify your original circuit to give more output...
A 3.3V peak-to-peak sine wave driving an 8 ohm load requires over 0.4 amps: a 2N3904 is too feeble for this current and would overheat in any case. You'd need a substantially more robust transistor. Your class-A amplifier would also run hot, requiring a heat sink on that transistor.

The 1.65V DC offset on that 0-to-3.3V input waveform also complicates biasing. By capacitively-coupling that waveform into a GND-referenced resistor, the sine wave will swing symmetrically +1.65 -to- -1.65 V. Now you can ground-reference the 8-ohm load resistor to those +6/-6 DC supplies.

It will be far easier to add a PNP drive transistor that can pull output down, while an NPN drive transistor pulls up (on alternate half-cycles). These transistors will still run warm, but having two shares the load in this class-B arrangement.
I have not shown high-frequency bypass capacitors on the DC supply going into the opamp...each supply should be bypassed to GND to warn-off potential oscillations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsiYme.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You have an 8\$\Omega\$ speaker and a 100\$\Omega\$ resistor from collector to +6V, so the most voltage you're going to get at the speaker is

$$
V_{pk} = 6V\cdot\frac{8\Omega}{8\Omega + 100\Omega} = 0.\overline{444}V
$$

and that's not even taking the voltage drop across the transistor into account.

You could try using a lower value collector resistor keeping in mind the maximum ratings of the transistor to get some more drive to the speaker, but more likely you'd want to use a different circuit such as a push-pull stage which would allow you to utilize the dual supply to get much more power to your speaker.